# ValueError When Using ModelCheckpoint in Keras Tensorflow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a pre-trained model, then remove the last few layers and use it for transfer learning within a new model, like so:

```
img_input = Input((96,96,3), name='img_input')

# PRETRAINED IMAGE MODEL
img_model = keras.models.load_model("img_model/saved_model")
img_model.load_weights('img_model/checkpoint/mdl_wts.hdf5')
img_model.trainable = False
for layer in img_model.layers:
    layer._name = layer.name + str("_img")
        
new_img_model = keras.Model(inputs=img_model.input, outputs=img_model.layers[-4].output, name='img_model')
new_img_model = new_img_model(img_input)

img = Dense(128)(new_img_model)
img = Dense(16)(img)
img = ELU()(img)

# Output
output = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='Final_Output')(img)
```

The model begins to train, but at the end of the first epoch I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/al/tf/train.py", line 68, in <module>
    model.fit(train_dataset,
  File "/home/al/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/al/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 149, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, **kwds)
  File "/home/al/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 142, in make_new_dset
    dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 87, in h5py.h5d.create
ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)
```

I think it has to do with my ModelCheckpoint callback:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('checkpoint/mdl_wts-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
```

I don't get the error if I exclude the loaded/pretrained model from the new model, so it obviously has something to do with that, but I don't know why.

Comment: The file you are trying to create already exists, delete it.

Comment: I have tried that - it still errors out the first time I run it with no saved model file or weights files present.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by changing .h5 to .tf in ModelCheckpoint.